# Rails reading cookies returns a string instead of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, activerecord

I have two controllers. My `Sellers controller` sets and reads cookies just fine.
In my `Titles Controller`, attempting to read cookies results in strings returned, instead of object.
So, `cookies[:user].id` works in `Sellers Controller`, but in `Titles Controller` it returns an error: `undefined method`shop_name' for "#":String`

Here's the code for  Sellers Controller:

```
class SellersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cookies

  def show
    @seller = Seller.find(params[:id])
    @user = cookies[:user]
    @shop = cookies[:shop]
    @listings = Listing.where(shop: @shop).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  private
    def set_cookies
      cookies[:user] = current_user
      cookies[:seller] = Seller.find(params[:id])
      cookies[:shop] = Shop.where(seller: cookies[:seller]).first
    end
end
```

Here's my `Titles Controller:`

```
class TitlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_data

  def index
    @titles = Title.last
  end

  private
    def find_data
      @shop = cookies[:shop]
      @seller = cookies[:seller]
      @user = cookies[:user]
    end
end
```

Inspecting the variables in the debugger gives me this output:

```
@shop
=> "#<Shop:0x00007f433f785dc8>"
>> 
@shop.inspect
=> "\"#<Shop:0x00007f433f785dc8>\""
>> 
cookies[:shop].class
=> String
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are string-based. So storing a non-String value to cookies needs to be serialised when setting the value, and then needs to be unserialised when reading the value. See [cookies docs here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html).

However, normally, you don't serialize database records because it might be stale already (not up-to-date to actual values in the database) once you get the `ActiveRecord` object back through deserialisation. Which is why I would recommend doing something below.

**app/controllers/sellers_controller.rb:**

```
class SellersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_seller, only: [:show]
  before_action :set_seller_first_shop, only: [:show]
  before_action :set_cookies, only: [:show]

  def show
    @listings = Listing.where(shop: @shop).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  private

    def set_seller
      @seller = Seller.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_seller_first_shop
      @shop = @seller.shops.first
    end

    def set_cookies
      cookies.signed[:user_id] = current_user.id
      cookies.signed[:seller_id] = @seller.id
      cookies.signed[:shop_id] = @shop.id
    end
end
```

**app/controllers/titles_controller.rb**

```
class TitlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_from_cookies, only: [:index]

  def index
    @titles = Title.last
  end

  private

    def set_from_cookies
      @shop = Shop.find(cookies.signed[:shop_id])
      @seller = Seller.find(cookies.signed[:seller_id])
      @user = User.find(cookies.signed[:user_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so so much :)